# Is it possible to reduce the character limit from 30

Tags: discussion

I've already had a couple of golf answers that were less than 30 characters - even with the character count included.

Is it possible and sensible to reduce that limit to 20 or 25 perhaps?

Comment: I'd expect all the trivial problems that can be solved in < 10 characters to crop up at least in public beta, though. How often do you think this would happen during the lifetime of this site?

Comment: I agree in general, but, in the interim, you can put in some filler text. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say a good answer should include an explanation of how it works, so there should be no trouble at all to write at least 30 characters.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that we should reduce the limit, but by how much we will only learn from usage. The examples you're likely referring to:

- [rot13](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4/rot-13-transform-standard-input/92#92): 5 char solution with about 9 additional characters that were necessary = 14 characters in total.
- [sqrt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73/re-implimenting-square-root/83#83): 11 characters with 11 other characters that were necessary = 22 characters.

I think 20 might be a useful limit, but as I say we'll see over time. For now, you could have added a link to the `rot13` function for the first one and explained to non-Python users that `**` is a power operator for the second. Both would tip you over the 30 character limit.

Answer (score 2):

I've been fortunate enough to be under the limit a few times and what it encouraged me to do was actually follow the guidelines for what constitutes a good [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) answer, including:

- Try to explain your solution.
- You should show how the program or function is executed, accepting the input, and printing the output.

Source: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info

Answer (score 1):

If you start with a header stating the language and number of characters used, it should help fill up enough reach the minimum character level.

---

### JavaScript (21 characters)

`alert("Hello world!")`